# How to query an Eloquent ORM many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have Staff who work in States (that is, states of Australia).

Staff are stored in the users table.  States are stored in the states table.  The many-to-many relationship between the two is stored in staff_state.

On my Staff model I have a method as follows:

```
public function workStates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Core\State::class);
}
```

I want to retrieve all users who work in the state of NSW, and have either a first name or last name that includes the letters 'dan'.  Here is my Eloquent query:

```
    $query = Staff::whereHas('workStates', function ($query) {
            $query->where('state_id', '=', 'NSW');})
        ->where('first_name', 'like', '%dan%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%dan%')
        ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('last_name', 'asc');
```

My query results all include the letters 'dan', however some of the Staff do not work in NSW.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the SQL query generated by Eloquent:

```
select * from `users` where (exists 
    (select * from `states` inner join `staff_state` on `states`.`id` = `staff_state`.`state_id` 
        where `users`.`id` = `staff_state`.`staff_id` and `state_id` = 'NSW') 
    and `first_name` like '%dan%' or `last_name` like '%dan%') 
    and `users`.`deleted_at` is null order by `first_name` asc, `last_name` asc
```

Thanks..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try grouping up the `first_name` and `last_name` conditions.

I think you can do this by passing a closure to the `where()` function. Maybe something like this:

```php
Staff::whereHas('workStates', function ($query) {
    $query->where('state_id', '=', 'NSW');
})->where(function($query) {
    $query
        ->where('first_name', 'like', '%dan%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%dan%');
})->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')->orderBy('last_name', 'asc');
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `state_id`, use the real column name from `states` table. 
 Also, group name related logic within [`where()` closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping). For example, if the column name is `name`:

```
$state = 'NSW';
$name = 'dan';
Staff::whereHas('workStates', function ($query) use($state) {
        $query->where('name', $state);
    })
    ->where(function($query) use($name) {
        $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%')
              ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
    })
    ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('last_name', 'asc')
    ->get();
```